# Android: strange SearchView's behavior

Tags: android, searchview

I'm trying to implement SearchView according to some online tutorials. But when i clicked the search icon, it did not expand, instead another search icon appeared to the left and i must click again; this time it worked.
Are there something i'm missing here?

Here are the captured images, sorry i can't post these to stackoverflow yet.
http://1drv.ms/186yI2Y

If i delete `collapseActionView` then it worked, but i can't customize search icon.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

In MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        mSearchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showResultsFragment();
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        boolean toggleHandled = mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        return toggleHandled || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your menu xml i changed `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="wrwrwr"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

and in your activity

```
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView; //don't import android.widget.SearchView
```

Comment: It's worked, thank you! I'm implementing using the AppCompat, guess i must use compat version of each element too :)